# Removing Info suggestions in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

I am writing my notes in VSC using LaTeX. However, it is bothering me that my text is highlighted with this blue squiggly line even though there is nothing inherently wrong with the code.

How do I remove this just for `.tex` documents as I also use VSC for java, python and more?

I have uninstalled and reinstalled a lot of exensions and sifted through the settings of VSC. However, as I am here nothing has helped.